# Wordpress - How to add an attribute to a plugin inline script tag

Tags: plugins

know how how to add additional attributes to an inline script tag of a plugin.

I mean for example this:

`<script type='text/javascript' id='nf-front-end-js-extra'>`

to this:

`<script type='text/javascript' id='nf-front-end-js-extra' data-cookieconsent="ignore">`

I tryed with...

```
function add_data_attribute_quater($tag, $handle) {
  if ( 'nf-front-end' !== $handle )
  return $tag;
  return str_replace( ' src', ' data-cookieconsent="ignore" src', $tag );
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_data_attribute_quater', 10, 2);
```

...but it works only for scripts with src file and not with inline scripts

thank you

Comment: It depends on how you're loading your inline script. Is it enqueued through WP or just placed in PHP somewhere?

Comment: If it's your plugin, use `wp_enqueue_scripts` to load the scripts. If (as I suspect) it's someone else's plugin, you'll need to contact the plugin's support team.

Comment: Yes it is. The plugin is Ninja Form. And I already contacted the support that tell me that they can't do nothing and I have to find solution in their full library of developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The script `<script type='text/javascript' id='nf-front-end-js-extra'>` is added via the `wp_localize_script` function, and you can't add attributes using the `script_loader_tag` filter. This filter can only be used for scripts added via `wp_enqueue_script`.

In your case, you should use the `wp_inline_script_attributes` filter.

Try using the following code:

```
// NAV: Add attributes to inline script nf-front-end-js-extra 
function wpcoder_to_script ($attributes, $javascript) {
    
    if(isset($attributes['id']) && $attributes['id'] === 'nf-front-end-js-extra') {
        $attributes = array_merge(array( 'data-cookieconsent' => 'ignore' ), $attributes);
    } 
    
    return $attributes;
    
}

add_filter('wp_inline_script_attributes', 'wpcoder_to_script', 10, 2);
```

You can add this code to the functions.php file or use the free [WP Coder plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-coder/) through the Global PHP page.

Comment: Thank you DmtLo, I tryed it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm. I tested this code by inserting it in functions.php and via the plugin WP Coder. Both methods work well for me. In what place did you insert the code?

Comment: in my functions.php

Comment: maybe try to insert the priority in `add_filter` from 10 to 50

Comment: umm, nothing change :(

Comment: Strange. Try to remove the code from functions.php and insert it using the plugin  [WP Coder plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-coder/). I try via the WP Coder and via the footer and code work correctly